# Write a Java program that takes two inputs: 1. text 2. a word or a phrase

Tags: java, string

> Write a Java program that takes two inputs:
>
> 1. text
> 2. a word or a phrase
>
> The program will read the contents text and search for occurrences of the search phrase in the file. The program should then replace all characters of matching occurrences of the search phrase with #.
>
> The modified file should be saved to a file in the
> same folder as the input file.
>
> Example: Search Phrase: "consectetur adipiscing elit"
>
> If the input file contains the following text
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cilium dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>
> then the output should be
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ########### ########## ####, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cilium dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

The code I wrote is given below. it does not changing the text with #

```
class GFG {
    static String censor(String text, String word) {
        String[] word_list = text.split("\\s+");
        String result = "";
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            stars += '#';
        int index = 0;
        for (String i : word_list) {
            if (i.compareTo(word) == 0)
                word_list[index] = stars;
            index++;
        }
        for (String i : word_list)
            result += i + ' ';

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String extract = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit , sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
                + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
                + "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
        String cen = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
        System.out.println(censor(extract, cen));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always much appreciated if you take the time to format your code well when presenting it on this, or on any question and answer site. Your small effort can help others better understand your code and your problem much more easily if you do this. Also, please show and tell what steps you've taken to debug your misbehaving code.

Comment: i have edited it. now take a look

Comment: I have formatted your code for you, please see how it differs from your own attempts to do this as your edits really didn't work. Again, though, what have you done to debug the problem? That is the crux of the issue, learning how to debug code, and applying those techniques to your own code.

Comment: If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class GFG {
    static String censor(String text,
                         String word) {
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if (word.charAt(i) != ' '){
                stars += '#';
            }else {
                stars += ' ';
            }
        text = text.replaceAll(word,stars);
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String extract = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit , sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." + "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur." + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
        String cen = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
        System.out.println(censor(extract, cen));
    }
}
```

I tried to keep the code similar to yours, i kept the building part of the * strings (it can be done better) and just used text.replaceAll('String to be replaced','* string') that change all the occurencies with the first argument with the second.

let me know if this works for you.

Btw the problem in your code was that you were splitting on the words but you wanted to change a whole substring.
If your need was to change the single occurrencies of the words that you are giving you should've splitted the words in an array, then you had to cycle on the array and do a replace for each word.